# What would be wrong with my nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I'm running a vue app, which is exposed to port 5000. I temporarily turned off the firewall and could confirm that the app is running. I am running this on GNU Screen, which I have done with prior sites with no problem. I can also confirm that this is not an issue with selinux.

The intent is to got with www -> non-www, https. These redirects are working correctly, I just can't get what's on port 5000 to show on the main url page.

```
server {
       listen       80;
       listen       [::]:80;
       server_name  www.{my-url}.com {my-url}.com;
       return 301   $scheme://{my-url}.com$request_uri;

       location / {
                proxy_pass http://{my-ip}:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                }

                error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
                }

                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
                }
}

server {
       listen 443 ssl http2;
       listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
       ssl_certificate         {path-ok};
       ssl_certificate_key     {path-ok};
       ssl_client_certificate  {path-ok};
       ssl_verify_client on;

       server_name {my-url}.com;

}
```

I've been trying to crack this all day. I've tried removing many things, variations on the ip, adding default_server to the 443, removing the servername from the 443 server, and pretty much everything. I just keep getting the default page at the url.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am running this on GNU Screen"?

Comment: "error_page 404 /404.html;", should that be "... /40x.html" ?  And what's up with the empty /40x.html and /50x.html locations?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, it's just the default nginx settings. I'll be fixing it up as I go along. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
return 301   $scheme://{my-url}.com$request_uri;
```

Every http request is redirected to itself, you probably get an endless loop in your browser.   "location /" is never reached.  Nothing seems to happen with the https requests.

Comment: Going to give an upvote for this since you are correct, not having https would be an issue. I failed to mention that I'm using cloudflare... they are only pointing to 443, and thus the redirect wasn't working because I was making the entry point port 80. Thank you for your help.